# Proving $Res(f'/f,z)$ is an integer for f analytic on a domain $\Omega$ and $z \in \Omega$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Here is what I have so far,

since f is analytic at z we know it is infinitely differentiable at z, so $f'(z) \not = 0$ and so we know that $Res(f'/f,z) = \frac{f'(z)}{f'(z)} = 1$ and any pole of higher order will be a multiple of this result so it will still be an integer. Is there a mistake in this reasoning, it seems a bit too simple but I think I covered all the possibilities for singularities of f'/f

Comment: No, try with $f(z) = z^2$ and the residue at $0$. The correct argument is that $f(z) = (z-a)^n h(z)$ with $h(a) \ne 0$ thus $f'(z)/f(z) = ...$

Answer (score 1):

The statement $Res\left(\frac{f'}{f}, z\right) = = \frac{f'}{f'}$ isn't quite correct. In general, if $g$ has an order $k$ pole at $z_0$ and $h$ has an order $k+1$ pole at $z_0$, then \begin{align*}
Res\left(\frac{g}{h},z_0\right) &= (k+1)\frac{g^{(k)}(z_0)}{h^{(k+1)}(z_0)}
\end{align*}
If $f$ has an order $k+1$ pole at $z_0$, then $f'$ has an order $k$ pole at $z_0$. Therefore \begin{align*}
Res\left(\frac{f'}{f},z_0\right) = (k+1)\frac{(f')^{(k)}(z_0)}{f^{(k+1)}(z_0)} = (k+1)\frac{f^{(k+1)}(z_0)}{f^{(k+1)}(z_0)}= k+1
\end{align*}